# how to pass variable location in 'from <location> import MyClass, my_function' paradigm

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-importlib

I am going to have a class and a function that differ depending on which client I am serving. However, I would like to have the class and function be invoked later in the pipeline using the same name each time. I've read that the import statement does not allow variables. But is there a way to mimic this code and get it to work?

```
def get_class_and_function_for_client(client):
    if client = 'client A':
        location = 'path/to/client/class_and_function'
    elif client = 'client B':
        location = 'path/to/client/class_and_function'
    else:
        <some default>
    from location import MyClass, my_function
    return MyClass, my_function

current_client = 'client A' # or sometimes 'client B'
MyClass, my_function = get_class_and_function_for_client(current_client)
mc = MyClass(<some data>) # could be the one defined for client A or client B
my_function(<some data>) # could be the one defined for client A or client B
```

Comment: [_`importlib.import_module(name, package=None)`_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module)